# How to run several classes in IntelliJ IDEA with same ordering?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Is there a way of telling IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition to run several classes in the same ordering one after another? Every class implements its own `public static void main(String[])` method.

I would like to avoid jUnit since it doesn't guarantee the same ordering of execution, though its nice it can execute each test in its own JVM.

Comment: What is the actual problem you are trying to solve this way? It could be that there is a better way, which solves the root issue, rather than treating the symptoms.

Comment: It's a simulation. A acts as both socket server and client connecting to B. B acts as server for A and server for C. C acts as a client talking to A and a client talking to C. Messages are being passed in a ring and I want to check how does the performance change with different implementations of C.

Comment: If you're using sockets, why not just run each in its own VM from IntelliJ IDEA? Do you expect to be restarting them frequently?

Comment: Yes, I do restart them frequently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your own maven mini-project with this plugin attached:
http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/

And then you can in IntelliJ add run configuration on this maven project with your goal.
I think this will be looking nice.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like this?

```
// write a main which calls
A.main(args);
B.main(args);
C.main(args);
```

If they have to run concurrently, you can add them as tasks to a ExecutorService. You can trap exceptions so that if one dies, they all shut down.

Comment: Good try, but I need them to run in separate JVMs. It can be done with a shell or batch script but then I couldn't run the script in debug mode.

Comment: I would make it so it can be tested all in the same JVM. i.e. not have singletons which prevent this from happening (or use ClassLoaders to work around the problem)  BTW: You can simulate a client-server sockets in just one thread. ;)